# Why the type doesn't match in this value swap code in C?

Tags: c, pointers

```
void swap(char *a,char *b){
  char t;
  t = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = t;
}
int main(void){
  char  a = '1';
  char b = '2';

  swap(&a,&b);
  printf("The value is %c and %c respectively\n",a,b);
  return 0;
}
```

in the above code, there's a spot that confuse me

I think if `a` is a pointer, and `*a` is the value it points to

```
int *ptr, a = 1;

ptr = &a;
printf("The value of *ptr should be a: %d\n",*ptr);
printf("The value of *a should be an hex address: %p\n",ptr);
```

so in the `swap(char *a, char *b)` function,it takes the value not pointer( *a not a),

`swap(&a, &b)`
but it actually pass the pointer value to it as the parameter, and the code works. Anybody can explain it to me?(I think for `swap(char *a){...}` part, the declaration doesn't mean it require *a to pass in, it means declare a pointer value `a`, not the value a points to as `*a`in elsewhere means).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` is confusing because it means two different, but closely related, things. In a variable *declaration*, `*` means "pointer". In an *expression*, `*` means "dereference the pointer".

It's intended to be a helpful mnemonic: if you have `char *a` in your code it means that `*a` is a `char`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function

```
swap(char *a, char *b)
```

takes two parameters, both of which are of type `char *`.  Quite literally that means they point to a character somewhere in memory.

When you dereference the pointer

```
t = *a;
```

You are saying "grab whatever `a` is pointing to and put it in `t`.

Perhaps the confusion is from the fact that `*` means two related but different things.  In the case `char *`, it's defining a *type*, specifically one that points to a character somewhere in memory.  In the case `*a`, the `*` means "look at the character being pointed to by *a* and let me know what it is".

Answer (score 0):

In `main`:

- `a` is a `char`
- `&a` is a pointer to the char `a`.

In `swap`:

- `a` is a pointer to a char
- `*a` is the char pointed to by `a`.

You passed a pointer to a pointer, and it worked beautifully.  Try drawing a picture with boxes and errors.  Clears things up every time.  Just remember your code has two `a`s and two `b`s.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the asterisk `*` has multiple meanings related to pointers:

- It be used in a declaration to introduce a variable that contains an address - a pointer:

  `int *ptr = NULL;`

  Similarly in an argument list, such as `void swap(char *, char *)`.
- It can also be used to *dereference* an existing pointer, or get the value pointed to, as within the function `swap`:

  `t = *a;`

This generally causes a good deal of confusion for students who are new to C, but it's actually quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

In this our aim is to swap the value

when you write char a='1'; i.e you are putting '1' at address 662442(suppose &a=662442).
char b='2'; i.e you are putting '2' at address 662342(suppose &b=662342).

now consider swapping a and b,here our aim is to **change value at 662442(&a) to value at 662342(&b)** and  **value at 662342(&b) to value at 662442(&a)**.

now for swapping we take a temporary variable *char temp* and will do the following

temp=*a; i.e assigning value at address 662442(&a) to temp.

*a = *b; i.e assigning value at address 662342(&b) to value at address 662442(&a).

now we will put previous value of a (i.e value kept in variable temp) at address 662342(&b)

*b = temp; i.e assigning temp to address 662442(&a)